# CAD Shapes in MS-Visio Import

Tags: shapes, visio, autocad

I want to extract all the shapes from a CAD file and use these shapes in MS-Visio with the correct sizing. I couldn't import them perfectly because I had already used add-ons in visio like "Import CAD Shapes."

Answer (score 0):

**IMHO** it is impossible! Add-in "Import CAD Shapes" always change size, and we cant change this offset...